# Airmon-ng and Intel 4965AGN: Cannot set channel

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireshark

I have troubles setting right channel when using Airmon-ng. This is what I have done.

1) sudo airmon-ng check kill
2) sudo airmon-ng check
Displays nothing

3) sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 11
4) sudo wireshark&
Wireshark reports that channel is 36 or somtetimes 6 (stongest channel is 11).

How can I force 4965AGN to channel 11?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and driver is iwl4695.

```
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on

mon0      IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Tx-Power=15     dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chanel can be set by iwconfig.

1) sudo airmon-ng check kill
2) sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
3) sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11